# How to make radio button groups connected?

Tags: html

I want to create two radio buttons, Small and Large. I want those two buttons on multiple places on my page so that when I click small on one of the buttons, all the smalls are checked. Is there a way to simply do that without calling a function in javascript?

Comment: @FrankPentangeli Please note that every question **must** include a [mcve] (code and details about the code) in the question itself

Comment: Radio buttons by their nature can only be selected one at a time per group

Answer (score 0):

This is done by assigning an `ID` property and then in the label use the `for` property and make it the same as the ID

```
<input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male">
<label for="male">Male</label>
```